# How make the indicies of the tkinter.text.get() function variable?

Tags: python, tkinter, text, widget

I cant get my indexes to work as a variable in the tkinter text widgets get function.

Many things that all point to one problem. I want to copy and insert code without a newline at the end of the line being copied and inserted. And I want it to work within a loop that will increment the line being copied by one every time. I can't get it to just grab 30 chars on line 1 and then next time the function "transferPrint(self, a)" is called grab 30 chars off line 2.
Also, I can't get it to insert at line 1 when coming from line 1 and line 2 when coming from line 2 and line 3 when coming from line 3 and so on...

This is basically a text box that copies to another text box, one line at a time. Or really, 30 chars at a time- char typed there or not (the length of one widget line)

```
from tkinter import *
import re 

class TextCompiler:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.a = 1.0
        self.countString = StringVar()
        self.countString.set("Current Processing Line: " + str(self.a))

        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.topLabel = Label(master, text = "Enter text to be compiled: ", bg = "green", fg = "black")
        self.topLabel.pack(side = TOP)

        self.windowIn = Text(master, height=20, width=30)
        self.windowIn.pack(side = LEFT)
        self.windowOut = Text(master, height=20, width=30)
        self.windowOut.pack(side = RIGHT)

        self.printButton = Button(self.frame, text="Compile next line?", command = lambda: self.transferPrint(self.a))
        self.printButton.pack(side = BOTTOM)

        self.quitButton = Button(self.frame, text="Quit", command=lambda: self.quitStuff(master))
        self.quitButton.pack(side = BOTTOM)

        self.count = Label(master, textvariable = self.countString)
        self.count.pack(side = BOTTOM)

    def transferPrint(self, a):
        b = self.a + 0.30
        #c=self.a+1.0
        endOfLine = "{0:.2f}".format(b)
        # = "{} lineend".format(self.a)
        #endOfLine = endOfLine + "\n"
        inputText = self.windowIn.get(self.a, endOfLine)
        self.windowOut.insert(self.a, inputText)
        self.a = self.a + 1.0
        self.countString.set("Current Processing Line: " + str(self.a))


    def quitStuff(self, master):
        self.frame.quit()
        master.destroy()

root = Tk()
TextCompiler(root)
root.mainloop() this is part of the program, wont go in the box
```

I think I already said what I want. What I'm getting is three things. 1-The insert just inserts at the end of the current string that is present in the output text widget. makes me think it is looking for "END" or "end" I don't know which one but I also think this is a problem caused by the overloaded index types this function takes. 
2-I'm getting only the chars that come before a new line in the result of the text.get() function call the way I have it typed.
3-The text widget will jump over lines of text that have no newlines searching for a newline. This throws off the line count index.

Comment: Your code does not run. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to include any imports and test data needed for it to run.

Answer (score 0):

> The insert just inserts at the end of the current string that is present in the output text widget.

Yes, if the index you specify is beyond the end, it will insert after the last character. For example, if you have a single line of text that is ten characters long, inserting at `"3.0"` will add it to the first line. If you want to create a new line you must insert a newline character.

Note: `END` is the name of a constant provided by tkinter. It is set to the string `"end"`. You can use either the string or the constant.

> 2-I'm getting only the chars that come before a new line in the result of the text.get() function call the way I have it typed.

That's too vague to address. The `get` function will always return the characters between the two indexes provided to it. If you're not getting the characters you expect, you're probably giving it bad indexes.

As I've said in other answers and comments to your questions, **indexes are not floating point numbers**. Rather, **indexes are strings** in the form of *line*.*character*. Thus, you need to use string formatting. You should *never* use floating point math when computing text widget indexes.

For example, lets assume you have a line number in `n` and you want to compute the index of the 30th character from the start of line number `n`. You can compute an index like this:

```
n = 1
index = "{}.0 +30c".format(n)  
# => "1.0+30c"
```

The first half of that converts the integer `1` to the string `1.0`, and then appends `+30c`. If you have the number of characters in an *integer* `y`, you could do this:

```
y = 30
n = 1
index = "{}.0+{}c".format(n,y)
# => "1.0+30c"
```

Note: This will only work if `x` and `y` are integers. In your code you are initializing `self.a` to a floating point number. A line number or a character number is an *integer*, and an index using those numbers must be a *string*.

For more information on the `format` method, see [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) in the official python documentation.

> 3-The text widget will jump over lines of text that have no newlines searching for a newline.

Again, the text widget will get whatever you tell it to get. It will "jump over lines" only if you give it two indexes that span lines.

Comment: I keep getting lost in problems. I find one bug and then another and then another, cat chasing his tail. Thanks for the help so far.